# If $X$ is an affine variety, how do we get that $I(X) \subseteq \mathfrak{J}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Assume $h \in \mathscr{O}_X(X)$. Then there exist $f, g \in k[X_1, \dots X_n]$ such that $h = \frac{f}{g}$, with $g|_X \not=0$.

If we have the ideal $\mathfrak{J}$ in $k[X_1, \dots X_n]$ defined as $$\mathfrak{J} = \{g \in k[X_1, \dots X_n] : hg \in \Gamma(X)\},$$

then how does it follow that $I(X) \subseteq \mathfrak{J}$?

Shouldn't $I(X) \cap \mathfrak{J}$ be infact empty? If yes, can I then say $Z(\mathfrak{J})\cap X$ is empty aswell? Also, can I claim $Z(\mathfrak{J}) \subseteq X$ when it is not true that, or without using, $I(X) \subseteq \mathfrak{J}$?

Comment: What is $\Gamma(X)$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 It is the coordinate ring.

Comment: What is $Z(\mathfrak{J})$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 The set of points over which every polynomial in $\mathfrak{J}$ vanishes. I thought this was standard notation, that's why I didn't explain.

Comment: About $hg \in \Gamma(X),h = \frac{u}{v}$ : $I$ is a prime ideal of $R = K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ and $v, u,g \in R, v \not \in I$. I think that $\frac{(g+I)(u+I)}{v+I} \in R / I$ is not the same as 
$\frac{gu}{v}+I \in R / I$.

Clearly if $g \in I$ then $\frac{(g+I)(u+I)}{v+I} = \frac{I}{v+I} = I \in R / I$ by the rules of multiplication in the field of fraction of $R/I$. Thus $I \subseteq \mathfrak{J}$